# How to host Font Awesome on GitHub

Tags: css

I want to host Font Awesome v4.7.0 on my GitHub account and use it with my Blogger website, but the RAW Link not work as the Bootstrap CDN.

Here's my GitHub: https://github.com/myfileshost/assets/tree/assets/lib/font-awesome

And the Bootstrap CDN is: https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css

Any suggestion to make it work!

Thank you!

I tried host it also on Firebase but not working.

Comment: What gives you the idea you should use GitHub as a file host for your Blogger website, or that that would be acceptable use for GitHub?

Answer (score 0):

Hosting assets like Font Awesome on GitHub and using them as a CDN isn't straightforward because the raw.githubusercontent.com domain serves files with a MIME type of text/plain.

Work-around:
Upload the Font Awesome files into the repo.
Enable GitHub Pages

You should then be able to link to the Font Awesome CSS like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://myfileshost/assets/tree/assets/libs/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Comment: Hi @David Fox, if I use the link you give its not working and there's no domain name on it so how we can reach the files with no domain name? Thanks

Comment: Excuse me, replace with the actual location in your github repo.
Enable GitHub Pages 

Updated:

```

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://github.com/myfileshost/assets/blob/assets/lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">

```